# Check if a game server is online nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, ping, game-development

I am currently wanting to write a program that involves checking whether websites or game servers are online. What would be the best way to check this, pinging or something else?

Are there any modules that allow this or help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some of the existing NPMs ? For example [is-online](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-online)